# Problems with django-extensions

Tags: django

I install django-extensions like that:

```
git clone git://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions.git
cd django-extensions
python setup.py install
```

Then I go to my project folder and use:

```
./manage.py graph_models -a -g -o my_project_visualized.png
```

Whats returns:

```
Unknown command: 'graph_models'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I try "help" - all of that commands I know, but how can I fix the problem with graph_models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you haven't mention it. I assume you're missing the `INSTALLED_APPS` step:

**settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_extensions',
)
```

Is's not mentioned on the [GitHub](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) site, but it is mentioned on the [documentation](http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/installation_instructions.html#installation).

And of course:

```
pip install django_extensions
```

And add it to the `requirements` if you have any

Comment: FYI, documentation link isn't working anymore. I could have updated the answer but suggested edit queue is full. Kindly improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it still didn't work then. I found out that I had to re-activate the environment (workon env_name). Then it worked.